# Does gapi.auth.authorize validate the OAuth2 token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-client

I understand a token received via...

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
```

...should be validated before use to prevent the confused deputy problem with a call similar to the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

...as specified by for instance Google here: [Validating the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken)

However if the token comes from the gapi.auth api, ie:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ "client_id": CONST.CLIENT_ID, "scope": OAuthScopes, "immediate": true, "include_granted_scopes": true }, handleAuthResult);

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        theAccessToken = authResult.access_token;
    }
}
```

...is the validation step already taken care of? I cannot find any Google documentation that makes this clear, and as a security risk, it would be good to hear from a reliable source.

Comment: If you set immediate parameter to "true" in gapi.auth.authorize, it make sure that user sees permissions dialog if they are not previously authorized. If the user is already authenticated, then user wont be prompted. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm getting at. I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer. What you said is also not quite right: an "immediate" fails with an error, at which point you can try again with "immediate: false" to put up the dialog (actually, as shown in the example in your link).

Comment: I am quite confused here. When you set immediate to true is it failing? with what error message?

Comment: Nope, everything works fine, but I'm asking about whether I need the extra security step. Read the "Validating the token" link to see what I'm talking about (basically after receiving the token, you should validate it to make sure it came from whom you're expecting, in this case, Google).